# Python Remove Lines Containing Non-Alphanumeric Tokens

Tags: python

Thanks for the help so far guys! Huge help

So this is my script so far,

```
import re
bad_words = '[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]'

with open('keywords.txt', encoding="utf8") as oldfile, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not re.search(bad_words, line):
            newfile.write(line)

lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
outfile = open('cleankeywords.txt', "w")
for line in open('newfile.txt', "r", encoding="utf8"):
    if line not in lines_seen: # not a duplicate
        outfile.write(line)
        lines_seen.add(line)
outfile.close()
```

How do I make it more efficient by remove the middle file processed: newfile.txt

So that both actions happen after each other. Additionally is there a way to specificy the input file location using something like tkinter, as well as the output name and directory

Thanks!

Comment: Use [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to check the line

Comment: You don't even need a regular expression.

Comment: `if all(i in string.ascii_letters + string.digits for i in line): newfile.write(line)`